# python setup.py install syntax error on Windows

Tags: python, syntax, module, docx

This is probably a dumb question but I am having trouble installing a module from a tar.gz file on Windows. The module is [docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx). Of course for docx one needs lxml and PIL which I had no problems installing because there are binaries available. For docx it appears I am out of luck.

So, I went about extracting the tarball with 7zip, using the command prompt to cd to the extracted directory with the setup.py file, then:

```
>>setup.py install
```

It appears to start working and then I get an error:

```
exec_(compile(source, fn, 'exec'), globs, locs)
File "setup.py", line 182
print "--- using Tcl/Tk libraries at", TCL_ROOT
                                    ^
```

Any ideas on this? Do I need a C++ compiler to run this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the module doesn't support your python version. In Python 3.x, `print` is a function, which is why it throws an error.

Either install Python 2.x, or forget this module. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you open cmd,command :
1.cd 'to folder save module need install'
path_to_python.exe setup.py build
...                setup.py install
done
example:

```
cd C:\Python\Packet\tornado
C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py build
C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install
```

Comment: Definitely not the problem, this

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late to answer, but for anyone else reading this question,
use [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/),  it's a better-maintained fork of PIL that works with python 3.x